# How to solve the Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am creating an application in Xcode where I need to add people in a UITableViewController with a name PeopleTableViewController and an Add Button in navigation bar is used to connect to NewPersonViewController i.e. is UIViewController.

But when I click on the "+" button it shows

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error.

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
 reason: '[<Draft3.NewPersonViewController 0x7f9148636650>
 setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
 coding-compliant for the key savePerson.'
```

Following is the screenshot for Main.Storyboard

[image]

Following is the code for NewPersonViewController:

```
import UIKit

class NewPersonViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var personNameTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        personNameTextField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        personNameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    }


    @IBAction func savePerson(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let person = People(title: personNameTextField.text ?? "")

        do {
            try person?.managedObjectContext?.save()

            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        } catch {
            print("Could not save the person's name")
        }
    }
}

extension NewPersonViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

Following is the code for PeopleTableViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class PeopleTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var peopleTableView: UITableView!

    var people: [People] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    //ViewWillAppear allows us to fetch all the data in the backend and help us display to the user
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<People> =  People.fetchRequest()

        do {
            people = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

            peopleTableView.reloadData()
        } catch {
            print("Could not fetch")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addPeople", sender: self)

    }

}
```

Comment: I'll guess that you created an outlet called `savePerson`, then deleted it in code and created an action with that name, but didn't remove the outlet connection in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your `@IBAction` and `@IBOutlet` are correctly binded to your storyboard ?

`'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key savePerson.'` feels like either the `@IBAction` or `IBOutlet` is not correctly binded, or that you didn't set the class correctly for your view controllers in your storyboard. looks to me like it is trying to access the method `savePerson` but cannot find it in the binded class.

Comment: Thx a lot. You were right savePerson outlet was connected in the main.Storyboard